# VisualStudio not saving Startup Window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, startup

Since a few weeks I have had this infuriating problem.
Whenever I start VS it opens an empty environment.
I tried to change that in Options > Environment > Startup from "Empty environment" to "Start window". After pressing "OK" I restarted VS completely and reopened it. Again: a new empty environment opens.

After reinstalling VS several times now I gave up and want to know, if someone had a similar problem and knows a fix for this problem.

Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (16.8.3)

**Installed Workloads from VS-Installer:**

- ASP.NET and web development
- Azure development
- Python development
- .NET desktop development
- Desktop development with C++
- Data storage and processing
- .NET Core cross-platform development

**Additional Extensions:**

- JetBrains ReSharper 2020.2.4
- Visual Studio Tools for Tizen

*all the extensions are up-to-date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After MONTHS I finally found a solution. I basically tried to uninstall all extensions and discovered that this issue only occurs while ReSharper is installed. I didn't find anything regarding this on the internet, therefore I searched all of the options and I finally found the issue!

If you have the same issue and have ReSharper installed (currently 2020.3.3) open Visual Studio and go to `Extensions/ReSharper/Options`. A new window will pop up. Then navigate to `Environment/Performance Guide` and under the group `Visual Studio preferences affecting performance` you'll find the item `Show empty environment at startup`. Set it from `Fix Silently` to `Ignore`. Click `Save` and close this window.

Additionally, you have reset the specific Visual Studio option. Therefore open `Tools/Options` and navigate to `Environment/Startup` and set the `On startup, open:` to `Start window`. Click `OK` and restart Visual Studio to check if the Start Window now gets displayed correctly.